# NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to click on link   Requirements, i have tried below code but they are all giving error.

1. `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Requirements")).click();`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Requirements')")).click();`
3. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text().,'Requirements')] ")).click()`
4. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='lib/general/frmWorkArea.php?feature=reqSpecMgmt")).click();`

   ```
   <frameset framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="70,*">
     <frame scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" name="titlebar" src="lib/general/navBar.php?tproject_id=0&tplan_id=0&updateMainPage=1">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      <body style="min-width: 800px;">
      <div style="float:left; height: 100%;">
     <div class="menu_title">

   <div class="menu_bar" style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 135px;">
   <div style="display: inline; float: right;">
   <a 1''="" tabindex="" accesskey="h" target="_parent" href="index.php">Desktop</a>
   |
    <a 2''="" tabindex="" accesskey="r" target="mainframe" href="lib/general/frmWorkArea.php?           feature=reqSpecMgmt">Requirements</a>
   |
    <a 3''="" tabindex="" accesskey="t" target="mainframe" href="lib/general/frmWorkArea.php?feature=editTc">Test Specification</a>
    </div>
   ```

Comment: Is it in any kind of frames? Have you used WebDriverWait? Which browser or all browsers?

Comment: Try to query your xpath in Chrome's developer console like this: `$x("[EXPRESSION]")` - does it work?

Comment: @ user1177636, yes it is inside a frame, i have updated question

Comment: Switch to that frame first, then use the Xpath..

Comment: @bit,can you guide me how to switch to frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must switch into the frame which contains the element, before attempting to use it:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("titlebar");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElementByName("titlebar");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
```

Then try to locate the required element..

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following XPath value:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@accesskey='r']")).click();
```

Comment: when i tried the code i got same error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@accesskey='r']"}

Comment: If it is inside frame, please switch to it using: `driver.switchTo().frame(); `